# Docker and Node js Error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

What am I dong wrong here?

The code works on my computer, but when I run it in docker it fails.

**I get the following error**:

> Error: Cannot find module
>   '/usr/src/app/src/Presentation/viewModel/index'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at /usr/src/app/app.js:29:18
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Object. (/usr/src/app/app.js:28:26)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:556:32) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1

I assume that the issue is not in docker since when I play with the **require** I can get different errors.

Just in case here is the docker file:

```
FROM node:8.9-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm start
```

Here is my app.js file which loads the module which failed:

```
// Load routes and load dependices - Views and ViewModel
routesConfig.getRoutes().forEach(function(route){
  var routeTmp = require(path.join(__dirname,'src/Presentation/viewModel/'+route[1]));
  app.use(route[0], routeTmp);
});
```

It failed at the require line....

When I play with the required files I get different errors, I assume that the module.export makes the problem but I don't know how to go deeper in debugging.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var serviceConfig = require('../../../config/service');
var navigation = require('../view/navigation/navigation');

// TODO
var Base = require('../../Core/Common/Base');
const base = new Base();

// Create service
const classTmp = base.getService().create(serviceConfig.getServices().baseService);
var user = classTmp.getAdmin();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  res.render('index', {
      title: 'Expasdress',
      fields: navigation.getNavigation(),
      user: user
    }
  );

});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the project sturcture:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── Jenkinsfile
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
├── config
│   ├── config.js
│   ├── createConfig.js
│   ├── domains.js
│   ├── routes.js
│   └── service.js
├── dive.log
├── k8s
│   ├── ingress
│   │   └── ingress.yaml
│   ├── pod
│   │   └── pod.yaml
│   ├── production
│   │   └── production.yaml
│   ├── rbac
│   │   └── fabric8-rbac.yaml
│   └── services
│       └── backend.yaml
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── icons
│   │   ├── add-thumbnail-placeholder.svg
│   │   ├── baseline-change_history-24px.svg
│   │   └── spartan-logo.png
│   ├── script
│   │   ├── app-view.js
│   │   ├── create-package.js
│   │   ├── sidebar.js
│   │   └── tag-input.js
│   └── stylesheets
│       ├── admin-base.css
│       ├── app.css
│       ├── base.css
│       ├── bootstrap
│       │   ├── css
│       │   │   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
│       │   │   └── bootstrap.css
│       │   ├── fonts
│       │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
│       │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
│       │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
│       │   │   ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
│       │   │   └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
│       │   └── js
│       │       ├── bootstrap.js
│       │       ├── bootstrap.min.js
│       │       └── npm.js
│       ├── component
│       │   ├── buttons.css
│       │   ├── create-components.css
│       │   ├── create-content.css
│       │   └── tag-input.css
│       ├── create-package.css
│       ├── login.css
│       ├── main.css
│       ├── material.css
│       ├── packages.css
│       ├── sidebar.css
│       ├── standard-list.css
│       ├── statistics.css
│       └── style.css
├── scratch
│   ├── access_token
│   ├── email
│   ├── image
│   ├── name
│   ├── refresh_token
│   ├── scope
│   ├── surname
│   └── userToken
└── src
    ├── Core
    │   ├── Abstract
    │   │   ├── Domain.js
    │   │   └── Service.js
    │   ├── Common
    │   │   └── Base.js
    │   ├── Database
    │   │   └── SQLiteDatabase.js
    │   ├── Factory
    │   │   ├── DomainFactory.js
    │   │   └── ServiceFactory.js
    │   ├── Observer
    │   │   └── EventObserver.js
    │   └── RequestHandler
    │       └── RequestHandler.js
    ├── Models
    │   ├── Domain
    │   │   ├── Component
    │   │   │   └── NameComponentDomain.js
    │   │   ├── Create
    │   │   │   ├── CreateDomain.js
    │   │   │   ├── DeleteDomain.js
    │   │   │   ├── EditDomain.js
    │   │   │   └── ReleaseDomain.js
    │   │   ├── List
    │   │   │   └── ListDomain.js
    │   │   ├── Login
    │   │   │   └── LoginDomain.js
    │   │   ├── Search
    │   │   │   └── SearchDomain.js
    │   │   └── Statistics
    │   │       └── StatisticsDomain.js
    │   ├── Entity
    │   │   ├── Admin.js
    │   │   ├── Plan.js
    │   │   └── Request.js
    │   ├── Mapper
    │   ├── Repository
    │   │   └── StorageRepository.js
    │   └── Service
    │       ├── BaseService.js
    │       ├── CreateService.js
    │       └── GetService.js
    └── presentation
        ├── ObjectMapper
        ├── view
        │   ├── app.pug
        │   ├── appsku.pug
        │   ├── component
        │   │   ├── addEquipmentTags.pug
        │   │   ├── addTags.pug
        │   │   ├── description.pug
        │   │   ├── imageLoader.pug
        │   │   ├── name.pug
        │   │   ├── plan-cell.pug
        │   │   └── title.pug
        │   ├── create-package.pug
        │   ├── create.pug
        │   ├── error.pug
        │   ├── exercise.pug
        │   ├── index.pug
        │   ├── login.pug
        │   ├── main
        │   │   ├── baseLogin.pug
        │   │   └── baseNonLoged.pug
        │   ├── navigation
        │   │   └── navigation.js
        │   ├── nutrition-plan.pug
        │   ├── package.pug
        │   ├── statistics.pug
        │   ├── tag.pug
        │   ├── workout-plan.pug
        │   └── workout.pug
        └── viewModel
            ├── Component
            │   └── Name.js
            ├── app.js
            ├── appsku.js
            ├── create-app.js
            ├── create-package.js
            ├── exercise.js
            ├── index.js
            ├── login.js
            ├── nutrition-plan.js
            ├── package.js
            ├── statistics.js
            ├── tag.js
            ├── workout-plan.js
            └── workout.js
```

I will be desperate enough to put my git code as well:https://github.com/tech-387/spartan-apps-admin-console-frontend

Comment: It has nothing to do with it, I have opened the image in dive and I got the structure which I expected. Also I wrote that I was abble to access the file to produce different errors and I assume that the issue lies in the module.export

Comment: `Presentation` vs. `presentation`?

Comment: @ChrisWhite needs to be lowercase but I'm not sure that that's the issue since the error shows the uppercase path

Comment: You're using the upper-case path in the routing: `var routeTmp = require(path.join(__dirname,'src/Presentation/viewModel/'+route[1]));` If your OS is case-sensitive, this would certainly seem to be the issue?

Comment: @ChrisWhite I will do everything lowercase and try it out

Comment: It's not that aslo you can see wha is the os that I'm running my project on FROM node:8.9-alpine